# Woocommerce wc_price filter usage

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

i have doubt regarding usability of wc_price filter , When i look the code [https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_price.html#489] i can find wc_price filter .

```
function wc_price( $price, $args = array() ) {
    extract( apply_filters( 'wc_price_args', wp_parse_args( $args, array(
        'ex_tax_label'       => false,
        'currency'           => '',
        'decimal_separator'  => wc_get_price_decimal_separator(),
        'thousand_separator' => wc_get_price_thousand_separator(),
        'decimals'           => wc_get_price_decimals(),
        'price_format'       => get_woocommerce_price_format(),
    ) ) ) );

    $negative        = $price < 0;
    $price           = apply_filters( 'raw_woocommerce_price', floatval( $negative ? $price * -1 : $price ) );
    $price           = apply_filters( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', number_format( $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ), $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator );

    if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', false ) && $decimals > 0 ) {
        $price = wc_trim_zeros( $price );
    }

    $formatted_price = ( $negative ? '-' : '' ) . sprintf( $price_format, '<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency ) . '</span>', $price );
    $return          = '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . $formatted_price . '</span>';

    if ( $ex_tax_label && wc_tax_enabled() ) {
        $return .= ' <small class="woocommerce-Price-taxLabel tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
    }

    return apply_filters( 'wc_price', $return, $price, $args );
}
```

This means this filter is used for changing the product price .

so now i want to double the frontend price by code . So iwrite the following function

```
add_filter( 'wc_price', 'double_price', 10, 3 );

function double_price( $return, $price, $args){
    $price=$price*2;
    return $price;

}
```

Now the price is showing in frontend without currency symbol .

then i rewrite it like this

```
function double_price( $return, $price, $args){
    $price=$price*2;
    return '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>'.$price.'</span>';

}
```

Now it's working .

But i don't think this is the correct way . **Can someone explain how can i use this function properly .**. What is the use of `$args,$price,$retun` in this filter ?

Also if i need to to change all product price based on category , how can i get product id inside this filter ? if i write the product id then i will write

```
function double_price( $return, $price, $args){
    $price=$price*2;
     if( has_term( 'shirts', 'product_cat' ,$product->ID) ) {
       $price=130;
     }

    return '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>'.$price.'</span>';

}
```

> Please note: this question have a sub question
>   [After using woocommerce_product_get_price hook the checkout page price is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788254/after-using-woocommerce-product-get-price-hook-the-checkout-page-price-is-incorr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hook `wc_price` is a formatting price hook… You should use instead `woocommerce_product_get_price` filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'double_price', 10, 2 );
function double_price( $price, $product ){
    return $price*2;
}
```

Tested and working

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> This hook is fired before any formatting price function and it's a composite hook based on `get_price()` method here applied to `WC_Product` object type.

Comment: but why  woocommerce_product_get_price  is coming under this 
  https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Deprecated_Filter_Hooks.html

Comment: But there is an error using this code . checkout page price is not correct.
for example the product original price is 10 . We double the price by this code . so the product price is 20 now . When i added this product to the cart then cart and checkout page price is 40 . That means this multiplication is take place in two times .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788254/after-using-woocommerce-product-get-price-hook-the-checkout-page-price-is-incorr

Comment: now please check that . i tried is_cart() and it is working in checkout page but the price show in the min cart -header cart still showing the error price

Comment: @Harry answered… check it.