# How can I change woocommerce product price on custom page, when I have some GET params?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have woocommerce products with regular price and sale price.
And I have users, who came from special url with GET param like:

```
site.com/customcart/?emailsale=true
```

How can I make regular users receive goods at a regular price, and users with a GET parameter receive a discount?

I've already tried this solution https://jeroensormani.com/disable-product-sale-prices-store-wide/

```php
$order = wc_create_order();
$order->set_customer_id(is_numeric($args['customer_id']) ? absint($args['customer_id']) : 0);
$order->set_total(0, 'order_discount');
update_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method', 'kassa-com');
update_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method_title', 'Kassa.com');
$order->calculate_totals();

$posts = get_posts($args); //get product by user role

foreach ($posts as $post):
    setup_postdata($post);
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $_SESSION['product_id'] = $product_id;
    $price = round( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', TRUE) );
    $sale =  round( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_price', TRUE) );
    $price_sale =  wc_format_sale_price($price, $sale) ;
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $price_html =  $product->get_price_html();
    echo $price_html;
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
woocommerce_product_loop_end();

<form method="GET" action="<?php echo $order->get_checkout_payment_url(); ?>">
<input type="submit"  class="btn btn-pink right" value="Pay">
</form>
```

Comment: 1. Please post the complete code scope. It's not possible to find out what you are trying to do in your code. 2. Does this url (site.com/customcart/?emailsale=true) redirects to a single product page or an archive page?

Comment: @Yashar https://pastebin.com/59ft6z9w

Comment: you can use `woocommerce_product_get_price` filter hook like: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788254/checkout-price-issue-using-woocommerce-product-get-price-hook) and check for your GET parameter in the hooked function.